# What does image0.dims == 2 mean? How can I solve this?

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
from cv2 import dnn_superres
import os

sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()
path = "D:/Nadia - Il segreto della Pietra Azzurra/EDSR_x2.pb"
sr.readModel(path)
sr.setModel("edsr", 2)

i = 0
for _ in range(39):
    i += 1
    fileprocessed = 'Nadia - Il segreto della Pietra Azzurra ' + str(i) + 'ep'
    print('Processando il file ' + fileprocessed)
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(fileprocessed + '.mp4')
    os.mkdir(fileprocessed)
    os.chdir(fileprocessed)
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    count = 0
    while success:
        cv2.imwrite('frame%d.jpg' % count, image)
        os.system("pause")
        image = cv2.imread('frame%d.jpg')
        result = sr.upsample(image)
        cv2.imwrite("frame%dup.jpg" % count, result)
        os.system("pause")
        success,image = vidcap.read()
        count += 1
    print('Concluso con il file ' + fileprocessed)
    os.remove(fileprocessed  + '.mp4')
    os.system('cd ..')
```

The error is the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\enhancer.py", line 24, in 
result = sr.upsample(image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-rwld3ghi\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:360: error: (-215:Assertion failed) image0.dims == 2 in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::blobFromImages'

The objective of the following program is to take a large mp4 video, cut it into individual frames and upscale them. Then I'll add a frame interpolation and a video from frames creator all with python, but I'm doing this one step at a time! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply, the listed function has a check to ensure that it works on *only* 2-dimensional images.  You somehow fed it an image with a different quantity of dimensions.  You need to check back through your data dependencies (`print` statements are useful) to see where you slipped into, say, a 3-D representation.

In particular, examine the `image` that you use in the indicated line.  Just before that, check with

```
print("image has", image.dims, "dimensions")
```

Comment: The result is an error, it says that NoneType object has not the attribute "dims", now I tried modifying the imread function adding % count after the name of the file, and it gives me back that this is a numpy array

Comment: Okay, so there's an even more basic problem with `image`.  You'll need to trace that through your code.

Comment: I solved, basically, I didn't add '% count', so the %d would not mean anything and Python would take nothing, and the object became a NoneType because it was Null. Changing that now I have my first part of the program working. Thanks a lot!!!